# In a quadrilateral $ABCD$, $AB=10$, $BC=33$, $CD=10$ and $DA=15$. If $BD$ is an integer, then $BD=?$

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

> In a quadrilateral $ABCD$, $AB=10$, $BC=33$, $CD=10$ and $DA=15$. If $BD$ is an integer, then $BD=?$

I was not able to do anything in this question. The quadrilateral has not been given cyclic, so we cannot apply Ptolemy's Theorem. I tried using cosine rule in $\Delta ABD$ and $\Delta CBD$ and obtained $$BD=\sqrt{325-300\cos A}=\sqrt{1189-660\cos C}$$ but was not able to proceed further from here.

How do I use the condition that $BD$ is an integer to uniquely determine the value of $BD ?$

Comment: I don't understand the close vote. This looks like a good question to me.

Comment: it seems that the value is 24

Comment: @user376343 Yes. 24 is the correct answer.

Comment: All you need to do is to apply triangular inequality in two triangles involving $BD$. There is only one possible integer value that gives a non-degenerate triangle

Comment: @MathLover Thank you very much! That is a much easier way to bound $BD$. I used the range of $\cos$ to find it's range and needlessly complicated the question.

Comment: @RiverX15 One clue here is that $CD+DA+AB=35$ is just slightly greater than $CB=33$ so the quadrilateral must be almost flat. This only leaves a very limited range for the diagonals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to estimate the minimum and maximum possible values of $BD$. It will probably help to draw a (reasonably accurate) picture.